# How can I remove unnecssary characters from a csv file

Tags: python

I want to remove all the special characters from the csv file. I tried in many ways but couldn't fix it

```
import re

data=("C:/Users/Niroshima/Desktop/Research/post.csv")
for i in data.values():
  i = re.sub(r'[^\x00-\x7F]', '', i)
  print(i)
```

And this error came up

AttributeError

```
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-ee7352e82dd3> in <module>
----> 1 for i in data.values():
2     i=re.sub(r'[^\x00-\x7F]','',i)
3     print(i)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'values'
```

Comment: Your data has no attribute `.values()`. You need to get the CSV file class. I'm guessing you would want to use something like `pandas` library or native `csv` module.

Answer (score 2):

`data` is just your file name, try opening the file and changing each line like so:

```
file_name = "C:/Users/Niroshima/Desktop/Research/post.csv"
with open(file_name) as f:
    for line in f:
        l = re.sub(r'[^\x00-\x7F]','', line)
        print(l)
```

If you want this data in another file, then you have to write each `l` to a different file